# How to get the correct GIT remote repository url

Tags: git

Please let me know how to get the remote url of a git branch that I did not clone to my local.

'git remote -v' is listing only the branch that I cloned this branch from and not any other remote branch urls.

I am facing problems to checkout from other remote branches and getting the error as 'does not appear to be a git repository'

Comment: Did you delete the `.git` directory by mistake?

Comment: `git remote -v` and pick the one you need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Does+not+appear+to+be+a+git+repository

Comment: 'git remote -v' is not listing my branch. For example I am using 'abc' branch but I am getting the url of 'development' branch

Comment: That is not listing all remote branches

Comment: Use `git branch -av` to list all branches

Comment: I tried 'git branch -av' and used 'git fetch remotes/origin/abc' but still got 'remotes/origin/abc does not appear to be git repository'. 'remotes/origin/abc' I got it from 'git branch -av' command

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote -v
```

it will show like this.

> origin xx@xxx(fetch)
>
> origin xx@xxx(push)

and then

```
git fetch origin (or other repo name show above)

git branch -a # this will show all the branches.
```

Comment: (or other repo name show above) it is not listing the repo name that I want to fetch

Comment: 'remotes/origin/abc' is listed with 'git branch -a' command but when I use it like 'git fetch remotes/origin/abc' then got the error as 'does not appear to be a git repository'

Comment: Yes it shown but that origin url is for 'development' branch

Comment: `git fetch origin`, and then `git branch -a`, list all the branch, and then `git checkout -b branchName origin/WantedBranchName`

Comment: how to get that wanted branch name? I am getting branch name as 'remotes/origin/abc' when I run 'git branch -a'

Comment: 'git checkout -b current_branch_name origin/remotes/origin/abc' is still giving the same above error

Comment: git checkout -b current_branch_name origin/abc